# access prompt asks for password when using howdy

Tags: login, password, keyrings

recently I installed howdy and start using it for authentication instead of entering password .

but when I enter my computer via howdy ,access prompt asks for password :

```
unlock login keyring
authentication required
the login keyring did not get unlocked when you logged into your computer.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't really change that. Your keyring is encrypted and decrypted with your password. The only way I could think of how to make this even possible theoretically would be to kinda extract the password out of your face information and then use that. But this just not works with face recognition because it's so inaccurate.

The only thing you can do is to either remove the keyring password completely or to change it to some other password and unlock it with some startup scripts. Both ways are horrible insecure, so use that approaches careful.

Here is a related issue: https://github.com/Boltgolt/howdy/issues/39